# what does this line means ? half += string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');

Tags: c++

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-palindrome-permutations-of-a-string/

what this line mean

```
half += string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');
```

in this code ?

```
void printAllPossiblePalindromes(string str)
{
    int freq[M];

    if (!isPalin(str, freq))
        return;

    int l = str.length();

    string half = "";
    char oddC;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if(freq[i] % 2 == 1)
            oddC = i + 'a';

        half += string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');
    }

    string palin;

    do
    {
        palin = half;
        if (l % 2 == 1)
            palin += oddC;
        palin += reverse(half);
        cout << palin << endl;
    }
    while (next_permutation(half.begin(), half.end()));
}
```

Comment: `i + 'a'` is trying to add a small integer to 'a' to get another character.  The expectation is probably that `'a' + 25 == 'z'` - the standard does not guarantee this, and there are are machines today where it is not true.  (The standard *does* guarantee that the equivalent trick for '0' to '9' works.)

Answer (score 0):

```
string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');
```

is coming from

```
string (size_t n, char c);
```

which is the fill constructor:

> Fills the string with n consecutive copies of character c.

so you are creating an onstance of the string class with

`size_t n` is replaced by: `freq[i] / 2` and `char c` with `i + 'a'`

and that string object is getting concatenated to the object `half` when you do:

```
half += string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');
```

Comment: I've just edited the wording of your answer for clarity.  Roll-back if you disagree.